# Aurelia and importing and using Highcharts X-range

Tags: javascript, highcharts, import, aurelia

I am using the Aurelia Framework and I just installed the Highcharts (v6.1.2) library for graphs etc.

When I import Highcharts:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
```

I am able to use the lib with the standard graph types like column/bar/line etc.

When I am trying to use a graph of type 'xrange' I always get this error:

```
Error: Highcharts error #17
```

according to which I haven't included the appropriate module for this type (it resides in /node_modules/highcharts/modules/xrange.js).

BUT when I do:

```
import Xrange 'highcharts/modules/xrange'
```

or just

```
import 'highcharts/modules/xrange'
```

I get that the module cannot be found!

Any idea on how to load the module I need??

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to add an entry to aurelia.json ? Im using amCharts which exposes some core reports but not all of them.

Comment: Have you tried to use other module (for example `highcharts-more` or similar)? Could you provide me with your code or something that I would debug?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the suggested method [Load Highcharts as an ES6 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts#load-highcharts-as-an-es6-module)

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
// Load the Xrange module.
import * as Xrange from 'highcharts/modules/xrange';
// Initialize Xrange module.
Xrange(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Hello and thanx! I still get "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'highcharts/modules/xrange'." It looks like the highchart modules are not exposed.